# image inside href link not working in ie7

Tags: html

I have embeded images as link in href tag, but the images are not working as link in ie7 although the same page is working fine in firefox and ie8. Can anyone help me out of it?

Here is the code

```
    <a href="example.com">
        <div class="banner_box_1">
            <img src="images/facilities.jpg" width="156" height="70" alt="facilities" />
        </div>
   </a>
```

The css applied on image div
.banner_box_1{
    width:156px;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 13px;

}

I think the problem is bcoz of css which is messing up in ie7

Comment: Please provide more details, sample code etc. Use fiddler
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: & what about the code you write so far ashish?

Comment: Please show some code. Are you using `position: relative`?

Comment: @Raj *fiddler*? For a broken image link?

Answer (score 1):

Images converted to base64 do not work in ie7, it's an ie7 bug :(

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/

Edit:
Can you even use `<div>` inside anchor ?