# A Href with Image not working in IE

Tags: image, html, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9

There was no solution listed for similar question: [image inside href link not working in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2665663/1152457)

I have image links that do not work in ie9 but work perfectly in Firefox & Chrome.
I know the problem is ie's approach to the nested div. When I remove it, the link works, but I would like to have it to standardize the box the image resides within.

```
<a href='http://www.weflect.com/obj_photos.php?obj_name=Christopher+Nolan&obj_id=1000003100634240'>
   <div class='img_m2'>
      <img class='size_m2' alt='Christopher Nolan' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/weflect-objects/1000003100634240-f741bdae22811aa18cb2b22eb395d404-35323-m2.jpg'/>
   </div>
</a>
```

Live site can be viewed: http://www.weflect.com/object/Christopher+Nolan/1000003100634240//

Also, swapping the order, by placing the 'a href' inside the div is not an option as I would like to be able to set different link locations to the same image. I could work it around to pass the link url to the obj_img function, but would rather not. Are there other answers to this issue?

Comment: add `onclick='window.open()'` to the image and change the cursor when over the image.

Comment: What do you mean 'standardize the box'? Why not standardize the images within links?

Comment: The easy answer is what I mentioned in my question:
position your <a href> within the <div> : <div><a href><img></a></div>

Should be easy to switch around your code to do that. Thanks to Mr. Disappointment for asking the right question to make me think why I needed it a certain order.

But lesson learned, IE does not like the <a href><div><img></div></a> order.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class='img_m2'>
<a href='http://www.weflect.com/obj_photos.php?obj_name=Christopher+Nolan&obj_id=1000003100634240'>
      <img class='size_m2' alt='Christopher Nolan' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/weflect-objects/1000003100634240-f741bdae22811aa18cb2b22eb395d404-35323-m2.jpg'/>
</a>
   </div>
```